# Limiting Access to SVN folders for certain users

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, svn, trac

I have created the file `svn.password` and added a few users.

Now I installed a **Subversion** repository and a **Trac** instance to my apache folder and set up the `vhost.conf` as follows:

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn/
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "SVN"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn.password
   Require valid-user
</Location>
<Location /trac/>
   SetHandler mod_python
   PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
   PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
   PythonOption TracEnv /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/trac/
   PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac/
</Location>
<Location /trac/login>
```

All running smoothly, I can access http://www.xyz.com/svn/repository and http://www.xyz.com/trac/ with any of the users I have added.

Now here is my problem. I would now like to limit access to certain folders within my repository for certain users. I want one repository for Trac but certain developers will only work on certain projects. So basically there is a xyz_server folder and a xyz_client folder in my ./svn/repository/.

I now change /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn/repository/conf/authz and set the following:

```
[/repository/xyz_server]
* =
test = rw
ihaveaccess = rw

[/repository/xyz_client]
ihaveaccess = rw
```

I would now assume, that if I try to access `http://www.xyz.com/svn/repository/xyz_client/` with the user `test` it would not work. Only if I tried accessing `http://www.xyz.com/svn/repository/xyz_server/` I should have read and write permissions.

However I have full access to the SVN folders.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your apache configuration, start by enabling `mod_authz_svn` module

> LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

Then inside `<Location /svn>` use the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` directive

> AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn/repository/conf/authz

Comment: I did so now, my vhosts.conf has the lines added, authz_svn_module was already loaded by default. However now no user has access anymore, I get a 403 Forbidden for all users.

<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn/
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "SVN"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn.password
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/svn/repository/conf/authz
        Require valid-user
</Location>

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, but in the end the problem was not with the authentication settings on the SVN server, but with my SVN client "Tortoise" which had been caching authentication data. So in the OP's example, even if I logged in as user "test" through Tortoise, it would use the access rules for the previously logged in user "ihaveaccess". Clearing the authentication data under "TortoiseSVN --> Settings --> SavedData" worked for me.